# Single Photo path going into multiple HashMap elements

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to to upload multiple photos to Firebase Storage, each photo should have its own unique path stored in a unique HashMap element that will be upload to Firebase Database.

For some reason, Every time the HashMap will be uploaded to Firebase Database, all the HashMap elements will contain the same photo path.

[This is a photo of the problem that I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AQM1.jpg)

This The Main Activity Code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mSelectimage;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Uri image;
    private String photoPath;
    final static int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
    int i;
    int j;
    int totalItelmsSelected;
    String push_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSelectimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        push_id = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();


        mSelectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final HashMap <String,Object> datamap = new HashMap<String, Object>();;
        datamap.put("image "+0,0);
        datamap.put("image "+1,0);
        datamap.put("image "+2,0);
        datamap.put("image "+3,0);


        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            totalItelmsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

            if (totalItelmsSelected <= 4) {

            for (i = 0; i < totalItelmsSelected; i++) {
                image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(image.getLastPathSegment() + ".jpg");
                filepath.putFile(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                     photoPath = filepath.getPath();
                     datamap.put("image " + i, photoPath);
                     mDatabase.child("users").child(push_id).updateChildren(datamap);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i + " Photos has been uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in Uploading " + i + " Photos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                datamap.put("Name","Kamil");
                datamap.put("Email", "Kamil@gmail.com");
                mDatabase.child("users").child(push_id).setValue(datamap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading to the database is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in registuring the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }else if (totalItelmsSelected >4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Choose only 4 photos ot less", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

This is build.gradle app Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammed.storemultipleimages"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[This is the result after removing the for loop containing j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2V69.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
     photoPath = filepath.getPath();
     datamap.put("image " + j, photoPath);
```

Here your `photoPath` is same for the entire loop so your `datamap` contains same paths.

The solution is to remove the for loop: `for (j=0; j<i; j++) {` in your code:

```
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    photoPath = filepath.getPath();
    datamap.put("image " + i, photoPath);    
    mDatabase.child("users").child(push_id).updateChildren(datamap);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i + " Photos has been uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I initially tried to do that but then the datamap for the the first three element was set to 0 and it only stored the photopath for the last element.

Comment: Could you post your code after edited like my suggestion here? It should work.